# Django commands being called by Crontab, but they are not executed

Tags: python, django, command, cron

I have my 'sudo crontab -e' set up as follows:

```
0 7,8,9,10,11,20 * * * /home/ubuntu/mydjangoapp/manage.py command >> /home/ubuntu/mydjangoapp/file.log
```

Today it executed correctly at 7am and 8am, however it suddenly stopped working... I have checked the /var/log/syslog and it says that the cronjob is being run, however nothing happens.

I tried changing the crontab to

```
0 7,8,9,10,11,20 * * * /home/ubuntu/mydjangoapp/manage.py command
```

then

```
0 7,8,9,10,11,20 * * * /home/ubuntu/mydjangoapp/manage.py command
```

and

```
0 7,8,9,10,11,20 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/mydjangoapp/manage.py command
```

However there was no success - /var/log/syslog was still saying that the command was being executed, but nothing happens.

I tried running a simple command such as

```
10 * * * * cat /absolutepath/file1 >> /absolutepath/file2
```

and it actually worked, so I thought it might work if I create a script.sh that runs my command:

```
!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/myapp/manage.py chronwakeup
```

but there was no success - then I thought, maybe my python path was not defined, so I added:

!/bin/sh
    export PATH="{$PATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_evolution-0.6.9-py2.7.egg:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dnspython-1.11.1-py2.7.egg:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5-py2.7.egg:/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7"
    /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/myapp/manage.py chronwakeup

However again, there was no success. I then tried creating a simple django command called dostuff.py containing only two print statements:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, make_option

class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    help = "Excecute Chron Wake Up Chron Roulette for the current batch of wake-ups."

    option_list = NoArgsCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--verbose', action='store_true'),
         )

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):

         print "doing stuff..."
         print "Done doing stuff."
```

and added the crontab command as 'sudo crontab -e':

```
43 7,8,9,10,11,20 * * * /home/ubuntu/myapp/manage.py dostuff >> /home/ubuntu/itworked
```

Once again, the command was executed, and the file was created, but nothing was created inside the file...

The weirdest thing is that it was working this morning, and it suddenly stopped working...

I would be really grateful if you could help me out!

Comment: Does `/home/ubuntu/myapp/manage.py dostuff` actually print anything?

Comment: Yes! It didn't! I fixed it - it was a misconfiguration in my settings file - thank you very much!

Comment: @axsauze what did you have to do in your settings file? I have a similar problem. Thank you